# Browser URL changes after http post fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have a login page on which the authentication can be successful or not. Here is the page `new.html.erb`:

```
<%=form_with scope: :session, url: sessions_path, local: true, html: {class: "login-form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email, t("session.new.email") %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password, t("session.new.password") %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit t('session.new.login'), class: "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

It is associated to a `sessions_controller.rb`, which is the following:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # Find the user with the matching email
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

    # Check the user exists in DB and that the provided password matches
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Log the user through the session helper
      log_in user
      # Redirect to the hive
      redirect_to ideas_path
    else
      # The authentication failed. Display an error message
      flash.now[:error] = I18n.t('session.new.invalid_credentials')
      # The render is done to reinitiate the page
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

In my `routes.rb`, I just have for this purpose:

```
resources :sessions
```

When executing `rails routes`, I have the following declared routes:

[image: Routes]

Now my problem is on the login fail. In my controller, in this case, I add a message in the flash messages and then re-render the same page `new.html.erb`. But in the browser, the login request POST has been sent on the url `/sessions`. The problem is the current URL on my browser becomes `/sessions` instead of staying on `/sessions/new`. This is as if the POST request changed the URL in my browser. But this is in fact just an AJAX request, isn't it?

I have found this [blog post](https://ryanlue.com/posts/2017-08-24-rails-render#fn:1) that wonders the same about this phenomenon (I'm not the author)

I have found a workaround, but I'd prefer avoid using it and understand the bevahior. If i replace my routes by the following, this works:

```
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
```

I can understand why this works: the get and post url are the same, so the browser doesn't change its URL.

Have you any idea?

**EDIT:**

I finally found a solution. I'm not sure this is the "rails way", but this works as expected. I have just changed the controller to do a redirection to the same page, with a flash request to transmit the login fail information:

```
def create
  # Find the user with the matching email
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

  # Check the user exists in DB and that the provided password matches
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    # Log the user through the session helper
    log_in user
    # Redirect to the hive
    redirect_to ideas_path
  else
    # The authentication failed. Display an error message through a flash
    # message after redirect to the same page
    redirect_to new_session_path, alert: I18n.t('session.new.invalid_credentials')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When the form gets submitted the browser performs a regular HTTP POST requsest to the /sessions endpoint. No AJAX there.

The way your routes are configured this POST request will be handled by your sessions#create action.

Notice the code there. You'll see that the happy path (successful login) calls [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to). In case of login errors though, the controller calls [render](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render).

The difference is that in the first case the response is a 302 Redirect which the browser follows. That's why you see the URL changing in the browser. In the second case the response is just 200 OK with a bunch of HTML for the browser to render. The URL won't change because the browser wasn't instructed to navigate elsewhere.

Here's an [extensive explanation of how redirects work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) in the browser in case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the associated doc. There's a point I miss: Why does the URL of my browser change when I submit a POST request? I thought this should only be the case on GET requests. Furthemore, what is the good approach with RoR for my use case?

Comment: Been trying to find some proper documentation on this that would explain it better than me, but no luck. Browser visits `/sessions/new`. Then you submit the form, so the last URL the browser knows about is `/sessions`. That's the "resource" that has been asked from the server. The server responds, and since it doesn't redirect, the browser will use that URL. Open up the dev tools in your browser and check the server response. The response URL is `/sessions`, right? Hope it makes sense :/

Comment: Yes, your answer helped me to understand. Now, I just have to understand how to use Rails correctly so that I can reach my goal :)